# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32

Tags: linq

I have this working T-SQL statement that I want to convert it to LINQ.

---------- T-SQL ---------

```sql
select o.Type, o.Name, SUM(Price) As Total
from Transactions t
inner join Orders o 
ON t.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
Group By o.Type, o.Name  
Order by o.Name
```

----- My Attempt -----

```sql
from t in db.Transactions
join o in db.Orders on new { CustomerID = t.CustomerID } equals new { CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(o.CustomerID) }
group o by new {
  o.Type,
  o.Name
} into g
orderby
  g.Key.Name
select new {
  g.Key.Type,
  g.Key.Name,
  Total = (int?)g.Sum(p => p.Price)
}
```

The above returns this Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is `Convert.ToInt32` call, why do you need it?

Comment: I get this "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'" if I remove it. Don't know why.

Comment: What is the **type** of `o.CustomerID`?

Comment: o.CustomerID is of type <b>Int</b>. Like I said T-SQL returns the correct result.

Comment: I meant in the C# code (the class `Order` or whatever it's called). There must be a reason for C# compiler complaining about join property types. `Convert.ToInt32` should definitely be removed. When you hover with mouse `o.CustomerID` inside the LINQ query, what do you see - `int`, `int?`, `string` or ?

Comment: Found it. Was defined as public Nullable<int>  { get; set; }. Removing Nullable removed the error. I stored the results into a ViewBag.summary_query = summary_query but I can't access the Total in the .cshtml file. Do I need to do something else to display it on .cshtml file?

Comment: Please disregard previous question. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating an anonymous type for the equals in the join? It doesn't serve any purpose.